# Boost windows 10 dell laptop speakers volume

Tags: audio, windows-10, volume-control

Any good software or in built feature in windows 10 (Dell laptop) for boosting volume?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend [Letasoft Sound Booster](https://www.letasoft.com/sound-booster-download/), but I don't know exactly if it works for dell laptops. It works fine on my Win 10 PC. However, it's a trial version. So you'll have to purchase it in the end. You can also try [Boom3D](https://www.globaldelight.com/boom/), [DeskFX Audio Enhancer Software](https://www.nchsoftware.com/deskfx/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

Go with **FxSound**! :'D

It was a paid, for-profit software,
but changed to a donation-funded software.
So, it's free!

Very good, I tell ya :'p

https://www.fxsound.com/changelog
(I'm on Windows 10 Pro)